# Explicit Intent is not triggerig in the fragment of TabWidget

Tags: android, android-studio

I added a Tabbed Activity and within the fragment there is a login button bottom of the two EditText views[image]

I have set the onClickListner within the onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) method and programmed the login button to open up a new activity by using explicit intent, but as soon as I hit the login button the application stops working. Point to be noted out here that I have not done anything regarding the authentication process but only programmed login button to open an activity.

```
package com.example.shashikant.bhuconnect;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static android.icu.lang.UCharacter.GraphemeClusterBreak.V;

public class Complain extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_complain2);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

       /* FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        }); */

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_complain, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        boolean studenLogin = false;


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_complain, container, false);
            ImageView personImage = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.personType);
            EditText EmailORId =(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.uniqueIdOrEmail);
            EditText uniqueId = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.uniqueId);

            // condition for switching to student login in TabWidget for registering complain
            if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==1){
                personImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.student);
                EmailORId.setHint(R.string.roll_number);
                uniqueId.setHint(R.string.enrollment_number);

            }
            //condition for switching to employee login in Tabwidget for registering complain
            else{
                personImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.employee);
                EmailORId.setHint(R.string.emailId);
                uniqueId.setHint(R.string.empId);
            }

           // TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            //textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            //button onClickListner will check if the email is vaild and direct to complain page
            Button loginButtonStudent = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
            loginButtonStudent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Complain complain = new Complain();
                    startActivity( new Intent(complain, WriteComplain.class) );
                }
            });
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 2 total pages.
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "STUDENT";
                case 1:
                    return "EMPLOYEE";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pardon me if  I have not explained myself, and thanks in advance.

Comment: "as soon as I hit the login button the application stops working" - in this case there usually is a crash report in Logcat (Android Monitor in Android Studio). Please add the crash log to your question.